# Android Studio editor show Navigation Action not found

Tags: android-studio, android-navigation

Some some reason, one of the navigation direction defined in in one navigation xml is not being recognized in Android Studio editor (any others are just fine):

```
val action = SomeFragmentDirections.actionXXXFragment() // Unresolved reference in editor
findNavController().navigate(action)
```

In the AS editor, it shows unresolved reference, but it is for sure in the navigation graph xml file and Gradle build, and the app run just fine.

Is there anything I need to concern about, or any way to get ride of the fake error if it is just one of the Android Studio thing?

Comment: Invalidate Cache and Restart?